# Javascript math not verifying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This project I am working on asks a multiplication problem and sends an alert to tell you if your answer is correct. The only problem is that when it verifies your answer, it does it wrong. Heres the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Math Facts Game</title>
        <style>
            h1 {text-align: center; font-size:28px;}
            h2 {color: green; text-align: center;}
            body {text-align: center;}
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <h1>Welcome to</h1><a href="https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Ethanlovessnakes/">epthesnakelover's</a><h1> math fact game!</h1>
        <h2 id="loading-bar"></h2>
        <br>
        Range: <input id="range1"> to <input id="range2">
        <br>
        <br>
            <button onclick="startgame()">Start</button>
        
        <div id="loader-container">
        </div>
        <script>
            function startgame() {
                var answer;
                var realanswer;
                rangeo = document.getElementById("range1").value;
                ranget = document.getElementById("range2").value;
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Loading";
                var y = document.createElement("BR");
                document.body.appendChild(y);
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif");
                x.setAttribute("width", "10%");
                x.setAttribute("height", "10%");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "Loader");
                document.body.appendChild(x);
                var one;
                var z;
                setTimeout(game, 3000)   
                };
            
            function game() {
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = ""; 
            
               
                one = Math.floor((Math.random() * ranget) + rangeo);
                two = Math.floor((Math.random() * ranget) + rangeo);
              
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "What is " + one + " X " + two;
                var y = document.createElement("BR");
                document.body.appendChild(y);
                var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
                input.setAttribute("id", "answer");
                input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Answer");
                input.setAttribute("type", "text");
                document.body.appendChild(input); 
                var y = document.createElement("BR");
                document.body.appendChild(y);
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                var t = document.createTextNode("Submit");
                btn.appendChild(t);
                btn.setAttribute("onclick", "go()");
                document.body.appendChild(btn);
            };
            
            function go() {
                answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
                realanswer = rangeo + ranget;
                
                if (answer == realanswer) {
                    alert("Correct!")
                    game();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Incorrect")
                    game();
                }
                
            };
            
            
        </script>
```

I tried troubleshooting with my dad, and he isn't advanced at coding (no offense dad if you happen to read this) but we couldn't figure it out. I know there are some very bright coders out there, and Please help me. All help appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: whats the answer yr getting? and whats answer are you expecting?

Comment: What is the expected answer?

Comment: console.log() is your friend. Learn to debug why it is not working. `console.log(answer, realanswer)` is it what you expect?

Comment: @epascarello my dad gave me that idea. we made it allert us what the computer thought realanswer is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dad figured it out. realanswer was the min rang time max range. I changed it to the first random (one) times the second random (two). It now works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Math Facts Game</title>
        <style>
            h1 {text-align: center; font-size:28px;}
            h2 {color: green; text-align: center;}
            body {text-align: center;}
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <h1>Welcome to</h1><a href="https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Ethanlovessnakes/">epthesnakelover's</a><h1> math fact game!</h1>
        <h2 id="loading-bar"></h2>
        <br>
        Range: <input id="range1"> to <input id="range2">
        <br>
        <br>
            <button onclick="startgame()">Start</button>
        
        <div id="loader-container">
        </div>
        <script>
            function startgame() {
                var answer;
                var realanswer;
                rangeo = +document.getElementById("range1").value;
                ranget = +document.getElementById("range2").value;
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Loading";
                var y = document.createElement("BR");
                document.body.appendChild(y);
                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                x.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif");
                x.setAttribute("width", "10%");
                x.setAttribute("height", "10%");
                x.setAttribute("alt", "Loader");
                document.body.appendChild(x);
                var one;
                var two;
                var z;
                setTimeout(game, 1500)   
                };
            
            function game() {
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = ""; 
            
               
                one = Math.floor((Math.random() * ranget) + rangeo);
                two = Math.floor((Math.random() * ranget) + rangeo);
              
                document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "What is " + one + " X " + two;
                var y = document.createElement("BR");
                document.body.appendChild(y);
                var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
                input.setAttribute("id", "answer");
                input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Answer");
                input.setAttribute("type", "text");
                document.body.appendChild(input); 
                var y = document.createElement("BR");
                document.body.appendChild(y);
                var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                var t = document.createTextNode("Submit");
                btn.appendChild(t);
                btn.setAttribute("onclick", "go()");
                document.body.appendChild(btn);
            };
            
            function go() {
            realanswer = 0;
                answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
                realanswer = one * two;
                alert(realanswer)
                if (answer == realanswer) {
                    alert("Correct!")
                    game();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Incorrect")
                    game();
                }
                
            };
            
            
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your variables `rangeo` and `ranget` actually contain strings, so when you "add" them you actually get the two strings joined together, not the numeric addition that you were expecting.

You could use e.g. `rangeo = +document.getElementById("range1").value` to turn that value into a proper number instead of a string (and the same for the other field too, of course).

Comment: Can someone explain the prefixed `+`. It's not an increment or short hand for `x = x + y`. The syntax is different from what I've always seen. I originally thought it was a typo; but, I'm having second thoughts.

Comment: @Tyler https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: It's a "unary plus", which when given a string input happens to convert the input to a number.

Comment: sorry, I meant to do  realanswer = rangeo * ranget;

Comment: NB: community wiki because I'm not here to get rep from a keen kid's question :)

Comment: btw I used your answer in my answer, @Alnitak